# Problem to build the right Regex with JS or JQUERY: replace all patterns between 2 strings in only one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a file with only one very long line:

```
{"cours":[{"BackgroundImage":"’images/1603881_teaser_picture_1599819830.jpg","UrlsCourse":["https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1603881-apprenez-a-creer-votre-site-web-avec-html5-et-css3","file:///R:/Formation/Développement/Apprenez ’ et CSS3 ’- OpenClassrooms.htm"],"description":"file:///R:/Formation/Développement/Apprenez ’ et CSS3 - OpenClassrooms.htm"],"file:///R:/Formation/Développement/Apprenez CSS3 - OpenClassrooms.htm"]
```

I need to replace all `’` by `'` which could exist between `file` and `htm` (URL) and keep the others `’` (there are lot of pairs `file...htm` inside the line.

I suppose regex could be a solution, but I don't see how to resolve this problem.

if no solution with regex, i will do a classic loop...

---

Another sample before after

before

```
"abc":"za’","[file///’ kje.htm]","[file///’ kje’ kje.htm]":"[file/// kje.htm]":"g’ kje"
```

after

```
"abc":"za’","[file///' kje.htm]","[file///' kje' kje.htm]":"[file/// kje.htm]":"g’ kje"
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you provide a *derived* example with a before and after (maybe only 20-30 characters) so we can actually see something?

Comment: Why would you not want *all* `’` replaced?

Comment: if i wanted to replace all `’` , the problem will not exist...

Comment: If the object was valid JSON this would be very straightforward. Do you have control over the output to correct it? Although, I suppose that if you did have control at that level it would be easier to prevent the invalid characters being entered in the first place.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, yes you have right its a json, and yes one solution will be to modify the url when called. but the best solution will be to fix the initial file (to avoid to pollute the js program ). I am thinking regex will be easier for an expert, but maybe the only solution will be to do a simple loop.. its challenge for regex expert..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
text = `{"cours":[{"BackgroundImage":"’images/1603881_teaser_picture_1599819830.jpg","UrlsCourse":["https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/1603881-apprenez-a-creer-votre-site-web-avec-html5-et-css3","file:///R:/Formation/Développement/Apprenez ’ et CSS3 ’- OpenClassrooms.htm"],"description":"file:///R:/Formation/Développement/Apprenez ’ et CSS3 - OpenClassrooms.htm"],"file:///R:/Formation/Développement/Apprenez CSS3 - OpenClassrooms.htm"]`;

// Build a regex to find all filenames ending with .htm
console.log(text.match(/file:\/\/\/.*?\.htm/g)); // <= This line is only for debug

// Use replace to capture filenames, and receive filenames in the callback.
// In the callback, call the replace function again to replace "’" by "'".
res = text.replace(/file:\/\/\/.*?\.htm/g,x=>x.replace(/’/g,"'"));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: yes its a good solution, i have forgotten the fact to use function() in replace regex..